# Set client_mtime metadata via dropbox API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'd like to be able to set the `client_mtime` in the dropbox file metadata. In the [dropbox api docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) it states

> **client_mtime** For files, this is the modification time set by the
>   desktop client when the file was added to Dropbox, in the standard
>   date format. Since this time is not verified (the Dropbox server
>   stores whatever the desktop client sends up), this should only be used
>   for display purposes (such as sorting) and not, for example, to
>   determine if a file has changed or no

I'd like to be able to set this via the API.  It clearly is possible to set because the desktop client does it but I can't find a documented way.

Is there a way to set this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replying to my own question a couple of years later...

The [Dropbox v2 API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) does allow you to set `client_modified` when you upload a file now.

You don't appear to be able to change it without uploading the file again though.

Comment: It works great for file. How to set timestamp for folders once they have created?

Answer (score 2):

*[This answer is out of date.  The Dropbox API v2 supports setting the modified time.]*

This can't be explicitly set via the API, though it does get updated to the current time when you upload a file via the API.